# Why program crashed with error SIG: 9 when execute the code context.getAssets().list("")?

Tags: android, assets

Why program crashed with error SIG: 9 when execute the code context.getAssets().list("")

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
String[] fileContents = am.list("");   //crashed here ,SIG: 9
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: why you are specifying blank string in argument? specify path.

Comment: @aksacha I want to get all files under the assets directory, the path argument is relative path, so I specify the blank string, but even if the argument is not empty string, it also cannot be access, the program crashed.

Comment: `AssetManager.list("")` will throw `IOException` because your path does not point a particular asset. If you claim that pointing to a valid asset path also crash, please post the path and the asset itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initView first, or the program will crash and becomes unstable.